# Using Fancybox 3 image galleries with or without thumbnails?

Tags: fancybox, fancybox-3

I have question concerning Fancybox 3. I have web page with many (10-15) image galleries each with about 50 images. Each gallery has one picture link on main page.
What fancybox use is better/more efficient?:

1. Using without thumbnails -> thumbnails grid is generated from big size images -> effect: when opening one gallery all big pictures are loaded.

   ```
   <p>
       <a href="big.jpg" data-fancybox="images">      
       <img src="small_thumbnail.jpg" />
       </a>
   </p>

   <div style="display: none;">
       <a href="big_1.jpg" data-fancybox="images"></a>
       <a href="big_2.jpg" data-fancybox="images"></a>
   </div>
   ```
2. Using with thumbnails -> thumbnails grid is generated from thumbnail small size images -> effect: when opening main page all thumbnails are loaded without any gallery openning.

   ```
   <p>
       <a href="big.jpg" data-fancybox="images">
       <img src="small_thumbnail.jpg" />
       </a>
   </p>

   <div style="display: none;">
       <a href="big_1.jpg" data-fancybox="images"> <img src="small_1_thumbnail.jpg"> </a>
       <a href="big_2.jpg" data-fancybox="images"> <img src="small_2_thumbnail.jpg"></a>
   </div>
   ```

Answer (score 8):

You have another option - use `data-thumb` attribute to store custom thumbnail image. Example:

```
  <a href="big-image.jpg" data-fancybox="images"
     data-thumb="small-image.jpg"></a>
```

Se this demo - http://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/yMxzvE?editors=1010 FYI, this can be any element, it is not necessary to be `<a>`.

If you do not want to create elements for each gallery item, but you are comfortable to write a bit JS, then another option would be to store gallery items in array and to use `instance.addContent()` method within `onInit` callback to populate current gallery, see this demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GbradR?editors=1010 or more general - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Gbraep?editors=1010

Comment: I have already updated default inline demo - http://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/jyEGGG/?editors=1000 There will be additional section at docs about data attributes.